# DataReader->ReadString throws exception

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have code below. Creating array of BYTEs, filling it with some sytes, and then trying to read it. When reading, i got an error:

```
int imageSize = 1024;
BYTE* input = new BYTE[imageSize];
// input is filling by some bytes..
DataWriter ^writer = ref new DataWriter();
writer->WriteBytes(ArrayReference<BYTE>(input, imageSize));

IBuffer ^buffer = writer->DetachBuffer();
DataReader ^ reader = DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer); 
auto res = reader->ReadString(buffer->Length); // THIS STRING THROW Platform::COMException ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings cannot contain random data - they must contain well-formed Unicode code-points. I assume the error (which you don't include) says this:

> HRESULT:0x80070459 No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

From the name of your variable (`imageSize`) it sounds like you're trying to load bitmap data, which is not a valid String.